# Especified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, sql

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, I have a datatable with the columns : 
integer numeromesa , string status and integer valortotal.

When I try to import the data with a select query to into my Pedido variable it gets me the cast error.
  This is the class that will receive the data from the table

```
public class Pedido
{
    public int numeromesa { get; set; }
    public int valorpedido { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }

}
```

Now this is the method I made use the select query

```
    public List<Pedido> listaPedido()
    {
        vsql = "SELECT * FROM pedidos";
        List<Pedido> bancoPedidos = new List<Pedido>();
        NpgsqlCommand objcmd = null;
         objcmd = new NpgsqlCommand(vsql, con);
                NpgsqlDataAdapter adp = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(objcmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                 //This is line 185
                    Pedido p = new Pedido
                    {
                        numeromesa = (int)row[1],
                        status = (string)row[2],
                        valorpedido = (int)row[3]                            
                    };
                   bancoPedidos.Add(p);

                    return bancoPedidos;
         }
```

The problem seems to be with the valorpedido variable if I take it out, the code works fine

************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   PostgreSQL.cs:line 185

Comment: indices are zero-based, so unless you have four columns in the resultset, it would have to be row[0], row[1], and row[2]. Better to index by column name. "select * from..." in connection with ordinal-based indexing is a very brittle approach.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be indexing from 0 instead of 1?

Comment: Is valortotal nullable? You mentioned a "can't cast to dbnull" in one of the other answer's comments.

Answer (score 2):

The original code addresses columns by index. Indexes start at zero, and they are prone to misalignment as the schema changes.
Instead, use names to access the columns:

```
var p = new Pedido
{
    numeromesa = (int)row["numeromesa"],
    status = row["status"].ToString(),
    valorpedido = (int)row["valortotal"]
};
```

This code assumes that neither `status` nor `valortotal` are nullable. If they were, you need to account for that, example:

```
public class Pedido
{
    public int numeromesa { get; set; }
    public int? valorpedido { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var p = new Pedido
{
    numeromesa = (int)row["numeromesa"],
    status = row["status"].ToString()
};

if(row["valortotal"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
{
    p.valorpedido = null;
}
else
{
    p.valorpedido = Convert.ToInt32(row["valortotal"]);
}
```

The performance penalty of looking up values by name instead of ordinal is negligible in this context (except when we're talking about tens of thousands of records), and gives you one important advantage: If the order of the columns ever changed due to modifications of the `pedidos` table or view schema, your code will continue to work. As it is originally written, it would break.

Comment: The index isnt the problem the [0] index in the table is a auto-incremented ID ,the [3] index is right. Tried changing to  names and i get the same error, where excacly i put that code to check if its null?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show this for the valortotal/valorpedido. if you have this pattern more than once, write a utility function to reduce clutter.

Comment: Dbnull.Value does not exist, tried only dbnull and also null, both get the same error "object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types

Comment: I made a spelling mistake. It is `System.DBNull.Value` with a capital "B". not sure about numeromesa, is it also nullable? if status really is a string, it would not matter.

Comment: numeromesa is the only column that has "Not null" set to YES". Im not really understanding the point of this equals.dbnull.value. If i remove the valorpedido, and use my insert query with numeromesa and status values only, it works just fine and displays the valortotal as Null. Not sure why it wont let me insert the valorpedido into valortotal...wierd

Comment: uh... what insert query? otherwise this is consistent with what we've got so far. `ToString()` works on a string column even when it is nullable, numeromesas is not nullable, so fine, and for valortotal we're properly handling postgre NULLs, which are ending up as DBNull.Value in .NET

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is on:

```
 valorpedido = (int)row[3]
```

The issue is that row[3] isn't of type integer when it comes out of the database.

Most likely you're off by one column because it's a zero based index with the data row.